# How To Register Interface<type, type>

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am attempting to setup dependency injection in my .Net 8 app and want it to scan and register based on naming convention.  Where I am stuck is I cannot figure out how to register `IFoo<in T1, out T2>` which someone created implementations of to setup custom mapping of objects. The specific implementations inherit from interfaces that inherit from `IFoo`.

Here is my DI code so far:

```
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
{
    var types = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType)).ToList();

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

        foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
        {
            // Register the interface mapping to the type in DI container
            services.AddTransient(@interface, type);

            // Register a factory for the Funcs
            services.AddTransient(typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(@interface),
                provider => new Func<object>(() => provider.GetService(@interface)));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how the classes are setup:

```
 public interface ISpecificFoo : IFoo<Member, SpecificFoo.Output>
 {
 }

 public class SpecificFoo : ISpecificFoo 
 {
     public class Output
     {
     }
 }
```

The error I am getting so far is:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type
> 'ISpecificFoo'
> for service type
> 'IFoo`2

Comment: Can you please add the "manual" code which would be analogous for your attempt. But in general - use [`Scrutor`](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not filtering out interface types, so if you have any interfaces that extend an `IFoo<in T1, out T2>` (as `ISpecificFoo` does), then that will be incorrectly registered as an implementation type.

You could do this:

```
var types = assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract) // Don't consider interfaces (or abstract classes).
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType))
    .ToList();
```

Now only instantiable types will be registered e.g. `SpecificFoo`.

To restrict this even further, you could specifically target just `IFoo<in T1, out T2>` as the service type:

```
var interfaces = type
    .GetInterfaces()
    .Where(i =>
        i.IsGenericType &&
        i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IFoo<,>));
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Johnathan's answer, so I won't repeat it. What I *do* want to warn about is your factory registrations. This is a memory leak waiting to happen. Let me explain.

You currently use this code to create a factory per found interface:

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(@interface),
    provider => new Func<object>(() => provider.GetService(@interface)));
```

This will, however, lead to memory leaks when the following conditions are met:

1. The `Func<T>` is (directly or indirectly) injected into a singleton consumer.
2. The implementation that `Func<T>` returns (or one of its direct or indirect transient dependencies) implements `IDisposable` or `IAsyncDisposable`.

Notice from the wording "direct or indirect" that it could be pretty hard to spot such problem just by looking at your code. Dependency graphs can become pretty deep and it can be hard to understand and analyze the complete object graph.

But why does this pose an issue? That's because, in the context of MS.DI, transient disposables are tracked by the container in the scope from which they are resolved. If a transient disposable is resolved from the root container (which is guaranteed to happen when a transient is directly or indirectly injected into a singleton, even though you might resolve the graph from an `IServiceScope`), a reference to that transient is stored in the container, and the transient disposable is disposed and references to it removed -only- when the container is disposed.

This is a problem, because there is typically only one container instance in your application, and it lives as long as the application lives.

Here's a an MRE that proves this point:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<Consumer>();
services.AddTransient<IDep, DisposableDep>();
services.AddTransient(sp => new Func<IDep>(() => sp.GetService<IDep>()));
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);

Console.WriteLine("Memory usage:");
while (true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        using var scope = provider.CreateScope();
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Consumer>().DoStuff();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} MB", GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1024 / 1024);
}

public interface IDep { }

public class Consumer(Func<IDep> factory)
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) factory();
    }
}

public class DisposableDep : IDep, IDisposable
{
    private byte[] someData = new byte[1024];
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

This program registers `Consumer` as a singleton. `Consumer` depends on `Func<IDep>` where `IDep` is implemented by `DisposableDep` which implements `IDisposable` and is registered as transient. To simulate memory pressure, `DisposableDep` creates a byte array. This exaggerates the issue, but the leak will already appear even if `DisposableDep` contains no data or dependencies of its own.

This is simplified example, in which case it's easy to spot the problem for a trained eye. But as I explained above, when you get into indirect dependencies which are disposable, it's very hard to spot, even for the trained eye.

So what's the solution? First of all refrain from using factory methods whenever possible; [they are a code smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/). For the few factories you might need, register them as scoped. This prevents them from being injected into singletons. While this might limit their use, it completely circumvents them memory leak altogether.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately that factory is not doing its job as it is still unable to automatically resolve services for Func<>.  Any tips on that?  The reason I am not using something like Scrutor is basically because our older app which I am upgrading is almost exclusively injecting Funcs and to my knowledge there isn't an IoC container that handles that out of the box.

Comment: I cant give you any tips with the `Func<T>`. The MRE I posted demonstrates a 'working' version; services are resolved. I think Autofac handles `Func<T>` out of the box, but with Autofac, you will certainly get into the same issue with memory leaks as you'll get with MS.DI.